# select everything from one table, and array from another

Tags: sql, join

I have one table that contains lots of data and I want to select everything from this one.

Another table contains different statuscodes ( fields `ID` and `text` ), and I want to join this table into the first one so i get something like

All data from first table `id1,text2,id2,text2` or `id1,id2,text1,text2` from the second table.

Comment: is there any relation between the tables?

Answer (score 0):

USe `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
Select T1.*,T2.ID,T2.Text
from firstTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable T2
on T1.<col>=T2.<col>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like this whether it may be **left/right/inner join**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.id,t2.text
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.column_name=t1.column_name
```

Comment: problem is that there is no match to be done, I want all available status codes to be joined in the first table. Just so I do not have to use two queries if that made sense ?

Comment: if there is no match means you have to use union/union all view this it may help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-union-keyword.htm

Comment: ah thanks, that explains a lot why I did not make this work:) thanx for the quick help guys